# Vector/Generics Searching java

Tags: java, generics, vector

Why do i always get '0' as the answer, am i doing something wrong?

I suspect the error is something to do with HistAndMarks method. What i'm trying to do is search through both vectors and count how many names are in both.

Thanks

```
public class Ex6 {

public static void main(String[] a) {
    Vector<Patient> P = new Vector<Patient>();
    Vector<Student> S = new Vector<Student>();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
    if (i == 0) {
        P.add(new Patient("Jimmy1", "1", "d"));
        P.add(new Patient("Jimmy2", "1", "d"));
        P.add(new Patient("Jimmy3", "1", "d"));
        P.add(new Patient("Jimmy", "1", "d"));
        S.add(new Student("Jimmy1", "1", null));
        S.add(new Student("Jimmy2", "1", null));
        S.add(new Student("Jimmy3", "1", null));
        S.add(new Student("Lisa", "1", null));
        System.out.println(new Ex6().HistAndMarks(P, S));
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        P.add(new Patient("Jimmy", "1", "d"));
        S.add(new Student("Jimmy1", "1", null));
        System.out.println(new Ex6().HistAndMarks(P, S));
    }
    if (i == 2)
        System.out.println(new Ex6().HistAndMarks(P, null));
}

public static int HistAndMarks(Vector<Patient> P, Vector<Student> S) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        for (Student students : S) {
            for (Patient patients : P) {
                if (S.contains(P)) {
                    count++;
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, first of all? Because your code has all kinds of bits that don't make the most sense.

Comment: Basically i want to search through the vectors and see if patient and student both contain the same name. For example if i enter 1 as my args then the computer should print out 3 because 3 names are the same in the vector patient and student

Comment: Then look at `S.contains(P)`, and your description of "see if their name is the same", and then see how that code doesn't in any way mirror your intention. You should be able to then see what the solution should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are iterating on the collections, but not using the elements you iterate on.

```
for (Student students : S) {
    for (Patient patients : P) {
        if (S.contains(P)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

`students` and `patients` should be singular, because they only represent one element of the collections `S` and `P`.

According to what you said you wanted to do, you should replace your loops by:

```
for (Student student : S) {
    for (Patient patient : P) {
        if (student.getName().equals(patient.getName())) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

This kind of `for` loops is called "enhanced for loop". It is just a simpler way of writing a loop to iterate on a collection.

```
for (Student student : S) {
    // some code using the variable 'student'
}
```

Is exactly the same as if you wrote:

```
Iterator<Student> it = S.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Student student = it.next();
    // some code using the variable 'student'
}
```

It is even simpler to understand with arrays. If `String[] tab;` is declared somewhere:

```
for (String s : tab) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(tab[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked perfectly, could you explain if possible what exactly for(Student student : S) does?

Comment: @user3364498 You're welcome :) I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: Thank you very much for adding that information, i really appreciate it!